# Zeros of an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is an entire function with $|f(z)|>|f(\bar{z})|$ for all complex numbers $z$ in the upper half plane. How does this imply that $f$ has no zeros in the upper half plane?

Comment: Where? If you're talking about zeros in the upper half plane then $f(z) = 0$ implies $0>|f(\bar z)|$ which cannot hold.

Comment: @Gortaur: I fixed it; I mean zeros in the upper half plane.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is simple: for each $z$ in the upper half plain $|f(z)|>|f(\bar z)|\geq 0$ hence $f(z)\neq 0$.

Comment: WOW, just that!